# Visual Studio 2012 Express not running files with .vb extension

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is related to work I am doing for school, but my issue appears to be a problem with a setting in the IDE not any of the code I am writing for my class.I tried searching for a related post, but nothing seemed close. If someone does find something I apologize for the duplication in advance and appreciate any guidance.

I have written some files using the Visual Studio IDE and they save out as .sln files which when I run them they go without an issue. Up until a couple of days ago files I had written before I could access the underlying .vb file and run without a problem.

However I must have mistakenly made some sort of settings change that I cannot figure out how to back out of. Now both the older programs and new ones the .sln files will run, but the .vb files will not. There is no error message, but any options in the IDE to run the code directly from the .vb file are greyed out. I even tried running vbc.exe from the developer command line on the files to see if there was some sort of language issue, but all of the .exe's built correctly and ran as expected. So I really have no idea what could be wrong at this point.

Has anyone ever heard of such an issue? Is there any setting related to Visual Studio that can account for this behavior? Thanks in advance for your patience and assistance.

Comment: A .vb file is not supposed to "run", it is supposed to be compiled to create a program that runs.  Be *very* specific about *exactly* what you see going wrong.  Copy/paste error messages, post a screenshot, try a simple "hello world" console project, use proper tags on your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running a sln or vb file. Sln is an xml file that describes where the other files are. The studio uses it to locate what belongs to your project(s). It does not run any of the files directly, rather it compiles all found files in one program.

Comment: @HansPassant as indicated in the post there is no error message just nothing happens when you press ctl + f5 similarly the debug -> run option is what is greyed out.

Comment: @GSerg when I say .sln file I mean file.sln located in filePath/project.sln that triggers a VS IDE window to open as opposed to filePath/project/project.vb which opens yet another kind of VS IDE window. The one that opens in the first case will "run" (as in ctl + f5 does something) the one in the later used to run, but for some reason no longer runs.

Comment: Right-click the project, select Properties, check Application, Compile and Debug tabs for making sense. If they do, try resetting VS settings (Tools - Import and export settings - Reset all settings). If that doesn't help, try repairing the VS installation (Control panel - Programs and Features - MS Visual Studio 2012 - Change - Repair installation).